# How can I fix the 'window is not defined' error while using react-leaflet and Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using Leaflet to generate a Map for my website, but it seems to be causing a `window is not defined` error.

I have been searching for a while and the cause of this issue appears to be that leaflet is attempting to load the map prematurely, as in before a window even exists, hence the error.

Alright so,

I have tried dynamically importing the Map from its source using `next/dynamic`

Example code:

```
  const Map = useMemo(
    () => dynamic(() => import("@/app/components/Map"), { ssr: false }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [location]
  );
```

I also tried using a `../components/Map` import instead of `@/app/components/Map`

Another thing that was mentioned is to use the dynamic import OUTISDE the main function, which would end up looking like this

```
 const Map = dynamic(() => import("@/app/components/Map"), { ssr: false });
```

Not only did this not fix my issue, it removes the reason I am using useMemo, which is to make sure that everytime the location changes the map is updated to go to that location.

Another thing that I tried was using an `isMounted` state where I'd make a useState, set it to false, and make it to true using useEffect

Example:

```
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
 setIsMounted(true)
}, [])
```

I'd have this in the Map component and have it only render if isMounted is equal to true as I had a return function to null before it

Example:

```
if(!isMounted) return null;

return (
 <Map></Map>
)
```

I have also tried messing around with the { ssr: false } option, removing it, making it true, but nothing worked. I keep consistently getting this error, so I'd love some help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the dynamic import outside of your react component or page, as it is the correct way to use `next/dynamic`. Lets say you had a prop that was called `location` that changes whenever you need your component to re-render, then you could do something like this:

```
const Map = dynamic(() => import("@/app/components/Map"), { 
  ssr: false,
});

interface Props {
  location: string;
}

export default function OtherComponent({ location }: Props): JSX.Element {
  // Since you want your component to re-render each time the location prop
  // changes, we pass the `key` prop to the component. This will force the
  // component to re-render.
  return <Map key={location} />;
}

export type { Props as OtherComponentProps };
```

As a side note, you are encountering the `window is not defined` error because the 3rd-party component tries to access Window API's that are not available on the server.

Comment: I tried this, I put the import outside of the component by the issue still persists...

Comment: Actually it seems like I have been sent down the wrong rabbit whole, as when I commented out all the times I've using the Map components & its imports the issue still occures