# having ReferenceError: window is not defined error for react leaflet during build process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet in my nextjs project. The project works perfect on dev mode but when I try to build it it gives `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I am also using ssr as false in dynamic but still gives the same error. Here is the code for further reference. any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

index.js

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

export default dynamic(() => import("./map"), { ssr: false });

// const  OpenStreetMap = dynamic(() => import('./map'), {
   //   ssr: false
// })

// const index = () => {
  //   return (
          //     <>
            //       <OpenStreetMap />
          //     </>
  //   )
// }

// export default index
```

map.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

const OpenStreetMap = () => {

   const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 43.64701, lng: -79.39425 })
   const ZOOM_LEVEL = 5
   const mapRef = useRef()

   return (
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL} ref={mapRef} style={{ flex: 2, 
        height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="mailto:rmubashir03@gmail.com" 
         target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Developed by Mubashir</a> &copy; <a 
             href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
              contributors'
             url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      />

        <Marker
          position={position}
          icon={icon}
          eventHandlers={{
            click: () => handleMarkerClick(marker)
          }}
        />
  </MapContainer>
 )
}

export default OpenStreetMap
```

Error

```
info  - Collecting page data ..ReferenceError: window is not defined
at D:\logistics-crm\logistics-crm\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:230:19
at D:\logistics-crm\logistics-crm\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:7:66
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\logistics-crm\logistics-crm\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:10:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
node:internal/process/promises:288
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at D:\logistics-crm\logistics-crm\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:230:19
at D:\logistics-crm\logistics-crm\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:7:66
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\logistics-crm\logistics-crm\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:10:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /apps/map/map
at D:\logistics-crm\logistics- crm\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1152:15 {
type: 'Error'
}
info  - Creating an optimized production build .info  - Collecting page data .
```

Comment: Whenever this type of error occurs i.e. `window` is not defined, try calling the respective code/component only on client-side.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as ReferenceError: window is not defined. Also in the next server terminal, there is error as ⨯ node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js (230:0) @ eval
 ⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined
I used dynamic from next/dynamic following this https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/956
But same here no fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. There is the way I resolved the problem as follows:

1. Add `map.module.css` file

```css
.map {
  height: 60vh;
 }
```

2. Export naming component as `MapComponent` instead of `default` in the `index.ts` file

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
export const MapComponent = dynamic(() => import('components/map/map-dealer'), { ssr: false });
```

3. My map-dealer.tsx file is as follows

```js
'use client';

import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import styles from './map.module.css';
import L from 'leaflet'

const DEFAULT_CENTER: any = [23.737704855705548, 90.40943564985567];
const size = 5;

const Map = ({ dealersList }: any) => {

  return (
    <MapContainer className={styles.map} center={DEFAULT_CENTER} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
      <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      {dealersList?.map((dealer: any, index: number) => (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          position={[dealer.latitude, dealer.longitude]}
          eventHandlers={{
            click: () => {
              console.log('marker clicked');
            }
          }}
          icon={L.divIcon({
            iconSize: [size, size],
            iconAnchor: [size / 2, size + 9],
            className: "mymarker",
            html: ``,
          })}
        >
          <Popup>
            <div>
              <p className="font-bold">{dealer.name}</p>
              <p>{dealer.address}</p>
            </div>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

4. Import this `MapComponent` to the parent component

```js
import { MapComponent } from 'components/map';

<div className="overflow-hidden mt-4">
   <MapComponent dealersList={dealersList} />
</div>
```

So make sure you import the `styles` from `map.module.css` because the map will be visible when `hight` is found and update it as needed.

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I have followed the exact same process but I still get the error while build process. I have made all my map in map file, then imported map in MapComponent file dynamically, and then imported that MapComponent file to index. But still getting same error. Not to forget I have also added 'use client' this time in map file. also am using js not ts.. so if possible please help me in js.. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I used the codes exactly and there is no error.

Please use this code https://codeshare.io/X8R9OM

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Are you also using build as on my side it's working in dev mode but not during build process

Comment: I have checked on my side right now. It is built successfully using the command `yarn build` which runs the `next build` command.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, and it is already what I had done before asking the question, so it didn't solve my problem. am writing the answer here as the above didn't solve my issue. I was using file structures like ***src/pages*** and ***src/views***. I moved all my component files like *map.js* and *mapComponent.js* to **src/views** and *index.js* to **src/pages** folder. This is important as the next.js first considers pages folder. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76304511/10840730) is the link that helped me solve the problem.

src/views/map/map.tsx

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import styles from './map.module.css';
import L from 'leaflet'

const DEFAULT_CENTER: any = [23.737704855705548, 90.40943564985567];
const size = 5;

const Map = ({ dealersList }: any) => {

 return (
  <MapContainer className={styles.map} center={DEFAULT_CENTER} zoom={10} 
  scrollWheelZoom={true}>
   <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
   {dealersList?.map((dealer: any, index: number) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      position={[dealer.latitude, dealer.longitude]}
      eventHandlers={{
        click: () => {
          console.log('marker clicked');
        }
      }}
      icon={L.divIcon({
        iconSize: [size, size],
        iconAnchor: [size / 2, size + 9],
        className: "mymarker",
        html: ``,
      })}
    >
      <Popup>
        <div>
          <p className="font-bold">{dealer.name}</p>
          <p>{dealer.address}</p>
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  ))}
  </MapContainer>
 );
};

export default Map;
```

src/views/map/MapComponent.js

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
export const MapComponent = dynamic(() => import('./map'), { ssr: false });
```

src/pages/index.ts

```
import { MapComponent } from 'src/views/map/MapComponent';

<div className="overflow-hidden mt-4">
  <MapComponent dealersList={dealersList} />
</div>
```